# How can I combine 2 commits into 1 in git in a branch?

Tags: git, version-control, git-branch, git-rebase

I was working in branch "Feature".
So my git tree was:

```
                  master
A<--B<--C<--D<--F<--G
            |<--E
                Feature
```

I wanted to get all the latest of master while working on Feature branch so I did:

```
git checkout Feature  
git rebase master
```

During the rebase I got a merge conflict in one file and during resolving the conflict manually I did a mistake which I realized later and not before running `git rebase --continue`
So I ended up with a tree as follows:

```
                 master      
A<--B<--C<--D<--F<--G<--E  
                       Feature
```

Then I realized about my mistake that actually broke the build in E.
I corrected my mistake (not commited yet) and continued my work but I don't want to have 2 commits in Feature that will end up in master and the one of the commits is a bad commit.
Also I would like to end up with a single commit in master branch of my work in Feature.
So if I have:

```
                 master      
A<--B<--C<--D<--F<--G<--E<--H  
                           Feature
```

How can I combine E and H into one commit so that when I do:

```
git checkout master  
git rebase feature
```

I have only 1 commit in my master?
Note:  The branch Feature is local and not pushed in case it matters.

Comment: Perhaps not relevant, but I have to ask: **Why?** The hole point of VCS is that you can _see_ who committed what, when and why. If you systematically rewrite your history, what's the point? Why not use tarballs to manage the source? So what if there are 2 or more commits visible, that's because there were several commits... why would you want to hide that?

Comment: @EliasVanOotegem:What is the point of having a commit that is a bad commit in history because of a manual/editing error?

Comment: I'd rather have bad commits than a fully rebased revision history... I value truth over a clean commit log

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use interactive rebase to combine two commits. You need to use the `squash` option on the second one.

Start with:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

in the editor, you will see 2 lines in this order:

```
pick E's SHA-1
pick H's SHA-1
```

replace it with

```
pick E's SHA-1
squash H's SHA-1
```

Then close the editor.
Git will pick E, then combine H to it.

You will be prompted for a new, combined commit message. Close that editor when finished and the rebase will finish by itself.

Comment: I should do this while I am on the Feature branch right?

Comment: yes, when you're in the feature branch in the last diagram of your question